# Поиск наиболее повторяющихся значений по фильтру

Tags: python

Есть массив с 2 колонками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как составить цикл или что применить, чтобы выявить какое значение из колонки 2 с каким другим значением из колонки 2 чаще всего встречается вместе в одинаковом значении параметра колонки 1.

Например из представленной таблицы для значения 600814: с ним вместе 3 раза встречается значение 24678, и 2 раза встречается значение 24754.

Как это оформить чтобы оно автоматически искало такие совпадения, и сортировало по убыванию кол-ва частоты встречи вместе.

Comment: вас интересуют соседи и сверху и снизу от числа?

Comment: "2 раза встречается значение 24754" - один раз.

Comment: 24754 - первый раз встречается со значением из 1 колонки 39003604, а второй раз со значением 39003354.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `Counter` и `defaultdict`, чтобы можно было создавать словарь словарей. А ещё `Counter` умеет сортировать ключи по убыванию частот методом `most_common()`. Плюс обеих структур состоит в том, что перед добавлением ключа не надо проверять его наличие в словаре, как это делается в `dict`-е.

Вот прототип кода с использованием этих структур:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

first_col_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for first, second in zip(first_col, enumerate(second_col)):
    i, elem = second
    if first_col_dict[first][elem] is None:
        first_col_dict[first][elem] = Counter()        

    if i - 1 >= 0:
        first_col_dict[first][elem][second_col[i - 1]] += 1
    if i + 1 < len(first_col):
        first_col_dict[first][elem][second_col[i + 1]] += 1
```

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: а можно более подробно рассказать про работу этого цикла?

Comment: Метод `zip` позволяет одновременно ходить по нескольким спискам одинаковой длины, поэтому нам в цикле доступны как и элемент списка А, так и элемент списка B (и даже соседние индексы в списке B). Затем создаём `Counter` для очередной пары элементов, если его ещё нет. И наконец, считаем соседей элемента из списка B.

Comment: не могу понять как этот цикл научить именно с моей таблицей работать. вот попробовала так сделать, но он не находит.. и я понимаю что он скорей всего в принципе не знаком с таблицей вот и не находит ее.. https://prnt.sc/v11jjv (извините за скрин, пока не разобралась как сюда вставлять код нормально.. )

Comment: А в каком формате у вас таблица? В виде Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Да, вот https://prnt.sc/v2avqv

Answer (score 0):

Если "скормить" в `Counter` кортежи, то он сам всё сделает:

```
from collections import Counter

arr = [(123213123, 1), (123213123, 2), (123213123, 1), (232132123, 1), (232132123, 2)]

Counter(arr)
```

Вывод:

```
Counter({(123213123, 1): 2,
         (123213123, 2): 1,
         (232132123, 1): 1,
         (232132123, 2): 1})
```